# assigning english and hebrew text to same uilabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, right-to-left, hebrew

I am maintaining an existing iOS project. I have to update text of a uilabel with half english text and half hebrew.

```
NSString *tempStr=[[LanguageManager sharedManager]languageString:@"Helpo Rank"];
self.rankLabel.text=@"";
NSLog(@"Helpo Rank assigned from .txt ---->%@",tempStr);
self.rankLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",tempStr,[self.professionalDetailDict objectForKey:@"ranking"]];
```

but the output beomes messy.[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AA3j.jpg)

Comment: Does it have to be on the same line? Is the issue because of the height of the label?

Comment: The ui label is automatically set to Hebrew because your first char is Hebrew. Then it sees there is English in it and it reverses the text from LTR correctly. Your problem is that the numbers and punctuation is considered English too instead of Hebrew. I guess there is a messy workaround. Is it good for you that I find it?

Comment: @Yitschak thanks for this help.... i will work about  it.

Comment: can you explain languageString function or add its code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use 3 ui labels:

The first is the localized string
The second is the separator
The third is the rank in numbers

That way the labels will be visually flipped automatically when layout changes from LTR to RTL and vice verse..

There is another workaround if you'll like